I am having trouble calling methods, and can't seem to figure out the correct way to call them
I'm writing a program to calculate the area and perimeter of a rectangle, and I can't seem to figure out how I will call the 3 methods.
I am not sure how to call the RectangleArea, perimeter and results methods in order to get the doubles I have created in them to print out in the results method.
Below I am calling them in the Main method, but I get an error that they don't exist in the current context, when I have my doubles commented out. If I uncomment them, I get another error telling me I'm using unassigned variables.
I have pasted the code below - if anyone could give guidance, I would greatly appreciate it.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Starter_Projects
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //double recarea, recperm, recres, width, height, perimeter, area;
            Height();
            Width();
            RectanglArea(width,height);
            Rectangleperimeter(width,height);
            RectResults(perimeter, area);
        }

        private static void Height()
        {
            double height;

            Console.WriteLine("enter the height of the rectangle");
            height = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        public static void Width()
        {
            double width;

            Console.WriteLine("enter the width of the rectangle");
            width = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        public static double RectanglArea(double width, double height)
        {
            double area = width * height;
            return area;
        }

        public static double Rectangleperimeter(double width, double height)
        {
            double perimeter = 2 * (width + height);
            return perimeter;
        }

        public static void RectResults(double perimeter,double area)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The perimeter of the rectangle is " + perimeter + "\n");
            Console.WriteLine("The area of the rectangle is " + area + "\n");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}


The following may be of interest: Understanding Scope and Visibility in C#

"I am not sure how to call the RectangleArea" - Is it because you misspelled it as RectanglArea?

@Dai although it's a misspelling it is not one of the actual problems here because it is [mis]spelled exactly the same in the declaration and when it is called in the code.

"Declaring" a variable is not the same as "initializing" a variable. And variables that are not initialized are treated as "unassigned"; which, depending on context, will cause errors. (An unassigned variable can be used as an "out" parameter; assuming the method in question does "initialize" the (out) parm at some point. So, uncomment the doubles and assign a value (using the literal "default" literal; or 0; or something else) "before" using them on the "right side" of an expression; or as a parm that is not an "out" parm.

Please see: What should I do when someone answers my question?.

Your code has several problems, related to these issues:

Scope of variables:
Local variables inside a method are not visible out of it, i.e. their scope is limited to the method.
Return a value from a method:
In order for a method to return a value, it should be declared to return a type other than void.
Then use the return statement to properly return a value from a method.
How to use a value from a method:
When the caller invokes the method (by calling it with (), it gets back the return value.
The caller can either use it directly (e.g. in another calculation/expression), or assign this value to a variable in order to use it later.

This is demonstrated below:
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    double height = Height();
    double width = Width();
    double area = RectangleArea(width, height);
    double perimeter = RectanglePerimeter(width, height);
    RectResults(perimeter, area);
}

private static double Height()
{
    Console.WriteLine("enter the height of the rectangle");
    double height = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    return height;
}

public static double Width()
{
    Console.WriteLine("enter the width of the rectangle");
    double width = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    return width;
}

public static double RectangleArea(double width, double height)
{
    double area = width * height;
    return area;
}

public static double RectanglePerimeter(double width, double height)
{
    double perimeter = 2 * (width + height);
    return perimeter;
}

public static void RectResults(double perimeter, double area)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The perimeter of the rectangle is " + perimeter + "\n");
    Console.WriteLine("The area of the rectangle is " + area + "\n");
    Console.Read();
}

Note: I also fixed a minor typo in method names etc.
Live demo
